# Regular Expression Asp.Net MVC

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to get a user name validations where the following texts are valid,

- Test
- Test2
- Tes2
- Test123
- 123Test
- 1234
- Test_56
- test-6ty

But not the following

- Tes (Min Length)
- Test@123 (Special char)

I added following annotations in Model, though does't seem to be working for the correct texts too. Keep getting the error message.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]$", ErrorMessage = "Only alphanumeric, hyphen and underscores are allowed for User name.")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
```

Comment: Are you saying that `ModelState` is valid when you submit with either "Tes" or "Test@123"?

Comment: No the ErrorMessage  will show fo even the correct once.

Comment: Which of the error messages?

Comment: The one for Regular Expression, "Only alphanumeric, hyphen and underscores are allowed for User name."

Comment: Your only allowing 1 character - use `^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*$` (or `^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{4, 100}$` to combine both as suggested in anubhava's answer

Comment: Thanks Stephan for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your examples it looks like this regex can be suitable for you:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{4,10}$"
```

`{4,10}` sets minimum length of input to `4` and max length to `10`. Change it whatever limits you want to keep.